# Llama2 model quantization using bitsandbytes

Tags: nlp, quantization, large-language-model, llama

I want to quantize the llama2 7B model using bits and bytes. I am using Windows and I installed bits and bytes-windows. I was able to quantize models on my machine before. But I'm not being able to quantize the llama2 model. I downloaded the llama2 model and saved it on my local disk. I have the following code:

```
            model_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, r"chatbot\downloaded_models\Llama7B")
            quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True)
            gpu_memory_allocated = torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0)
            print(gpu_memory_allocated)

            gpu = 14 - gpu_memory_allocated
            cpu = 64

            if gpu > 0:
                gpu = f"{gpu}.0GIB"
            else:
                gpu = 0
            if cpu > 0:
                cpu = f"{cpu}.0GIB"

            model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path,
                                                            local_files_only=True,
                                                            device_map='balanced',
                                                            torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                                                            load_in_4bit=True,
                                                            quantization_config=quantization_config,
                                                            max_memory={0: gpu, 'cpu': cpu})
             # disable Tensor Parallelism 
            model.config.pretraining_tp = 1

            tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, local_files_only=True)

            print(model.get_memory_footprint())
```

How can I achieve this in this code?